# how to enable GPS Automatically in android Oreo?

Tags: android, kotlin, gps, location

sorry for that because this question asked very time but i want to get user location in emergency condition so probably the user GPS possible not enable at this time also Internet.

so how i enable GPS at this time or other way to get location at this time without GPS and Internet ?

please provide code if possible? highly appreciated

**android 8.1**

Comment: You can't force GPS on if it's off. The user needs to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I put my comment in answer field because of this restriction: 'You must have 50 reputation to comment'.

There is this 'Last Known Location' in the 'Fused Location Provider API'. Check them out.

Comment: It might not be available at all or it might not be the true current location anymore.

Comment: i used fused location but not get location ...can you please refer to code ?

Comment: Of course it is not the true current location since GPS/internet service is down. Would you rather have it turned on remotely? That would probably violate some privacy laws in certain countries. In situations like this, it would be better to use the 'Find your phone' feature.

Comment: "find your phone" ?

Comment: It's an app written by Google. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.adm